# You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page

Tags: google-api

I can't enter `Credentials` or `Consent screen` via `Google Console Developer`

I'm admin, sometimes it's allow but most of the time it not

I don't know why. Have anyone be like this?

[image]

**NOTE**

I also use incognito mode , clear cache, clear data but no hope.

Comment: Same problem. Very annoying, all the "solutions" don't work

Comment: yes, it doesn't work

Comment: I wonder how we can report to google

Comment: This crappy bug has been flying inside my nose for nearly 2 days already. anyone knows a solution to this?

Comment: I just got into the credentials page. 'must have been something to do with the dual accounts access or so. (facepalm)

Comment: as I mention incognito mode of chrome would solve dual accounts access but still sometime can view credentials page and most of the time not.

Comment: got any solution. am also facing same issue.

Comment: has google changed anything in last couple of days regarding this? I tried from 3 different machines and 2 different accounts but getting same error.

Comment: I'm having this problem as well. I'm trying to access this at work and I wonder if the corporate proxy isn't the culprit.

Answer (score 43):

In top left corner there is a spinner for project selection(see the attached image), if you **select some other project** from the drop down of spinner the issue most probably will be solved.

You can select back your project from that menu.

It solved my problem

[image]

Answer (score 17):

Please try logging out all other accounts and login only one account then you try it will work. Even I had the same issue now I'm able to do it. If that doesn't help try to login with some other account and try again.

Comment: Just switched to another browser other than Chrome and it worked fine. In Chrome, switched Chrome's profile from my every-day account to my admin account and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: I recommend keeping the Google account you normally use for Cloud/Developer Console as your primary account. That is to say: the first account you log into in a Google session, and the first account in the list in the drop-down in the upper-right corner.

Answer (score 5):

This is most probably due to dual account access. I had to make sure that I was signed in as the same person (the button next to the minimize button on chrome browser) as the account I was using to login into the developers console to gain access. Hope this helps.

Comment: Argh, Google vs. Google: I'm using Chrome with my everyday account, but I'm signed into Console specifically with my admin account. Switching Chrome to my admin account (and still logged in to Console as admin) works. Thank you.

Comment: @Varsha - This helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In Apis enable 'Google Play Developer API'. This error disappeared after that for me. Wierd bug

Comment: I don't see that API. I do see 'Google Play **Android** Developer API'. Following the answers below about dual accounts worked for me: either using a browser other than Chrome, or switching Chrome itself to my admin profile.

Comment: This led me to a solution. After I enabled the 'Google Play Developer API' as instructed I was able to search for the API I was looking for. +1

Answer (score 0):

I was able to view the page but unable to create the service account.

Remedied as follows

1. First sign out of any other account.
2. Create the service account (you receive the error message)
3. Refresh the screen and the account is displayed, from the settings tab click to generate the public / private keys.

Comment: This worked! Why in the world did it worked???Also If someone else has this issue,try different names,maybe without spaces.You have to be creative!

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the page -> application -> cookies -> right click on the link & then clear. After clearing cookies then reload page & signin again. I hope it works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31385613)

Answer (score -2):

May be the connection you are using has proxy settings, I faced the same problem , when connecting via proxy server and when i went back home and used without proxy , the page simply opened.

Answer (score -2):

In case anyone has this problem: If you're using the Moesif Origin & CORS Changer chrome extension, you need to disable it. Otherwise it breaks the console

Answer (score -2):

I faced the same issue, in my case, I had a chrome extension to unblock CORS, when I removed this extension from Chrome. Google started working just fine again.