# Google Developer Console's credential side permission

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I got an problem after i create and APIs on Google Developer Console and enable the GCM service, 
but i want to add an server key at **Credential** next to **APIs** on left hand menu.
But it show me **You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page.**
Below are the image:
[image: You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page.]

Is that any config i need to add?
I did follow what [You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31869154/you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissions-to-view-this-page) to clear cache and use incognito mode to login, but still not work.

**EDIT**
Some time i relogin  it work back, when i click to another side and click back it show the error again, and my solution is go to **Credential** than use top right corner account to logout and relogin , let it redirect you back to **Credential**, than it work. So is there any solution to fixed it permanently without relogin?

Thanks

Comment: same here. Didn't know if it is a bug or we just missed some setting

Comment: Now my method not work already, after logout with using right corner and relogin, it redirect me to home page, not the page i stay anymore. I think google fixed the redirect bug.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. After following the below steps it got solved. This may help you as well.

1. Click on Apis under Api & auth
2. Click on "Google Play Game Services".
3. Enable the service.
4. Optional: enable "Google Play Developer API" as well. Most of the time it will enable by default.

Comment: Cant find 'google play services' as suggested in step 2. which section it comes in?

Comment: Sorry It should be 'Google Play Game Services', 'Google Play Developer API'

Answer (score 1):

It because of you have logged in multiple devices. so u have to log out from all devices. to do this go to gmail.com and log in using your email and password. and scroll down . you can see Details link . Click that link. [image]

it will open new window. there u click [image]

Sign out all other web sessions. than clear history. than do login and try . it will open without showing error.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issues.
Try using another browser like firefox - sometimes it works.
but after awhile, same error pops up.

Comment: tried on a different browser, incognito window, etc., but it didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue as with you regardless what api i enable.. have tried all the suggestion posted earlier. but none of them worked, but when i tried to change my i.p.. using a vpn. and tried to access it.it worked, i can create or view my api now,tested it with other gmail account to confirm and started from scratch. to my surprise i didnt encounter that issue im having for hours.. no idea why my i.p is being rejected when accessing the credentials area..

Answer (score 0):

I've resolve my issue, it's about the ISP you are using. I tried 3 ISP's and 1 of them got a success all the time, I don't have any permission error.